# Is there a level limit in dojo treegrid?

Tags: dojo, treegrid

I've trying to get the treegrid using forestmodel to work the last several days. It seems to me that there is a limit to the number of level can be displayed using programmatically created treegrid.
I modified dojo's "dojox/grid/tests/test_treegrid_model2.html", once I add another level under "Ottwa", I got a "dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore: Invalid item argument." error.

...
{ id: 'CA', name:'Canada', type:'country',  population:'33 million', area:'9,984,670 sq km',
     children:[{_reference:'Ottawa'}, 
               {_reference:'Toronto'}]},
{ id: 'Ottawa', name:'Ottawa', type:'city', population:'0.9 million', timezone:'-5 UTC',
      children:[{_reference:'Ottawa1'}]},
{ id: 'Ottawa1', name:'Ottawa1', type:'city1', population:'0.9 million', timezone:'-5 UTC'},
...

If I add the 2 new cities to Canada, it works just fine.
...
{ id: 'CA', name:'Canada', type:'country',  population:'33 million', area:'9,984,670 sq km',
 children:[{_reference:'Ottawa'}, 
          {_reference:'Toronto'},
      {_reference:'Ottawa1'},
      {_reference:'Ottawa2'}] },
{ id: 'Ottawa', name:'Ottawa', type:'city', population:'0.9 million', timezone:'-5 UTC'},
{ id: 'Ottawa1', name:'Ottawa1', type:'city1', population:'0.9 million', timezone:'-5 UTC'},
{ id: 'Ottawa2', name:'Ottawa2', type:'city1', population:'0.9 million', timezone:'-5 UTC'},
...

Is there a limit to the number of level can be displayed in TreeGrid?
Thanks,

David

Comment: I was pointed to this opened ticked: http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10945, I guess it's not fixed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm answering my own question, and hopefully it'll be useful for other people. It is a confirmed [bug](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10945), the bug fix is scheduled to be released with 1.6. But if you check out the most recent trunk(http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/), and just update your TreeGrid.js, it should fix the problem.